# Fetch for copyField returns empty results... Is this expected behavior with Solr search?

Tags: solr

```
            <schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
            <types>
            <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.StrField"  />
            <fieldType name="searchTokenizer" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
                <analyzer type="index">
                    <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory"/>
                    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
                    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />  
                 </analyzer>
                <analyzer type="query">
                    <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory"/>
                    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                </analyzer> 
            </fieldType>
            </types>
            <fields>
            <field indexed="true"  name="field_id"   stored="true" type="searchTokenizer"/>
            <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="company"  stored="true" type="searchTokenizer"/>
            <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="include" stored="true" type="text_general"/>
            <field name="actualCompany" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
            </fields>
            <uniqueKey>field_id</uniqueKey>
             <copyField source="company" dest="actualCompany"/>
             </schema>
```

I have used the below query: 
    http://localhost:8983/solr/listSearch/select?q=*%3A*&fl=actualCompany&wt=json&indent=true
But I got the result as follows: 
                    {
                      "responseHeader":{
                        "status":0,
                        "QTime":1,
                        "params":{
                          "q":"*:*",
                          "indent":"true",
                          "fl":"actualCompany",
                          "wt":"json"}},
                      "response":{"numFound":420550,"start":0,"docs":[
                          {},
                          {},
                          {},
                          {},
                          {},
                          {},
                          {},
                          {},
                          {},
                          {}]
                      }}

What is wrong with the copyField. Please advice me.

Comment: Did you reindex your core after adding the copyField statement?

Comment: @Uwe Allner:  I have used the command  java -Dtype=text/csv -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/listSearch/update -jar post.jar  list.csv      and then i have stopped solr instance and restarted again. is this fine for re-indexing?

Comment: @Uwe Allner: Hi, as you mentioned here, issue is with re-indexing. Now i have created new core having the same schema, it worked as I expected. Then what are the steps and commands should be followed for re-indexing whenever i am redefining schema for the same core. I am very beginner to solr. Please help me. I have used below commands to create core and indexing

Comment: cd solrHome/bin  ,   solr start    , solr create -c <core schema name> -d basic_configs , java -Dtype=text/csv -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/coreName/update -jar post.jar  datalist.csv   , solr stop -all, start solr